# Exclude Brackets Tags

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that selects everything between tags, but not what is bold, like this:

```
[capti id="attachment_2231" align="alignnone" width="950" caption="ABC"]AEAEAEASEASEA[/caption] ***ABCDEFGHIJKLMN*** [capti id="attachment_2231" align="alignnone" width="950" caption="ABC"]AEAEAEASEASEA[/caption]
```

The regex that I'm trying is `\[([a-z]|[A-Z])* (.*)\[\/([a-z]|[A-Z])*\]` but it selects everything, including what is bold.

Is there anything different I can do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes, don't use regexes to parse html-like text. I'm guessing that's some kind of bbcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better option than using regex would be doing a replace on your bold text by an empty string and then keep the remaining content.

```
$string = '[capti id="attachment_2231" align="alignnone" width="950" caption="ABC"]AEAEAEASEASEA[/caption] ***ABCDEFGHIJKLMN*** [capti id="attachment_2231" align="alignnone" width="950" caption="ABC"]AEAEAEASEASEA[/caption]';
$pattern = '/\*{3}\w+\*{3}/i';
echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $string);

// output
[capti id="attachment_2231" align="alignnone" width="950" caption="ABC"]AEAEAEASEASEA[/caption]  [capti id="attachment_2231" align="alignnone" width="950" caption="ABC"]AEAEAEASEASEA[/caption]
```

But if you want a regex, you can use one like this:

```
(\[.*?\].*?\[.*?\])
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/sT3bY2/3)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-95]  `[capti id="attachment_2231" align="alignnone" width="950" caption="ABC"]AEAEAEASEASEA[/caption]`
MATCH 2
1.  [117-212]   `[capti id="attachment_2231" align="alignnone" width="950" caption="ABC"]AEAEAEASEASEA[/caption]`
```

Comment: @Morris glad to help. If my answer answered your question you may consider marking your question as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

A regex might not be the best solution, but you need lazy matching to limit the amount of characters that get matched, so `.*` would become `.*?`.

Also, simplifying the selection of the tags by matching all characters until the closing tag:

```
\[[^\]]+\](.*?)\[\/[^\]]+\]
```

See the [example](http://regex101.com/r/sT3bY2/2) at regex101.